# Can't get the Datatable Instance from a ViewChild

Tags: angular, datatables

When I attempt to access the `dtInstance` of my DataTable ViewChild I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Declaring ViewChild in component:

```
@ViewChild('dtuser') dtuser: DataTableDirective;
```

Method that destroys the datatable instance:

```
searchByCoid(term: string): void {
console.log("user: ",this.dtuser);

this.dtuser.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {dtInstance.destroy();});
this.getUsersByCoid(term.trim());
//this.getLoggedInCompanies(); 
}
```

The output of the Datatable object into console (when calling the method above):

```
user:  
ElementRef {nativeElement: table#DataTables_Table_0.row-border.hover.dataTable.no-footer}
nativeElement
:
table#DataTables_Table_0.row-border.hover.dataTable.no-footer
__proto__
:
Object
```

**HTML**

```
<table #dtcompany datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptionsComp" [dtTrigger]="dtTriggerCompany" class="row-border hover">
    <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let d of companylist" (click)="selectCompany($event, d)" [class.highlighted]="d.highlighted">
    <td>{{d.id}}</td><td>{{d.name}}</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>

<h1>Select User to Modify</h1>
<table #dtuser datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptionsUser" [dtTrigger]="dtTriggerUser" class="row-border hover">
    <thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Company ID</th><th>User ID</th><th>PAIOS Acct ID</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let c of userlist">
    <td>{{c.firstname}}</td><td>{{c.lastname}}</td><td>{{c.companyId}}</td><td>{{c.user_id}}</td><td>{{c.PAIOS_acctid}}</td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: whats your html code and which datatable are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @ViewChildren instead of @ViewChild:

```
  @ViewChildren(DataTableDirective)
  dtElements: QueryList<DataTableDirective>;

  // ...

  searchByCoid(term: string): void {
    this.dtElements.forEach((dtElement: DataTableDirective) => {
      dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {dtInstance.destroy();});
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DataTableDirective

```
@ViewChild(DataTableDirective) datatableElement: DataTableDirective;
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatable-destory